# Добавление Activity view indicator в экран загрузки

Tags: ios, xcode

Экран загрузки основан на launch image set. Для всех типов устройств. Необходимо добавить activity view indicator, чтобы при загрузке было видно этот индикатор

Answer (score 1):

Launch Image set это просто набор картинок для каждого устройства. Если вы хотите добавить индикатор загрузки, создайте контроллер, и сделайте его initialize. Затем на вьюху добавьте ту же картинку и индикатор загрузки.

Comment: А как делать если Приложение будет использоваться на всех типах устройств ? Картинки для каждого разрешения автоматом будут меняться? Так же Приложение пишется для iPad

Comment: а как вы обычно ставите картинку на фон для любых типов устройств?

Answer (score -2):

Не уверен, что понял вопрос. Предполагаю, что вы хотите показать индикатор загрузки на splash screen. Если так то:

Добавить его на splash не получится.

Что можно сделать: после запуска приложения на первом `ViewController` показать ту же картинку, что и сплэш (картинку отдельно добавлять не надо, можно использовать сам сплэш) и на ней уже добавить activity indicator. Поскольку вам надо знать, на каком устройстве вы грузитесь, чтобы поставить соответствующую картинку, для этого нужно узнать размер экрана - `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` и на основании этого уже выбрать изображение.